# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in PDO Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to execute a insert query but it is throwing me this error I am not able to understand what the problem is! Please help me out! thank you in advance:)

```
    $count_query_params = [$fromDate, $toDate, $TRNO];
    $count_query = "INSERT INTO `$HA_ENTRIES`(`fromDate`, `toDate`, `user_trno`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $count_row = db_query_all($count_query_params, $count_query);
```

`// DB_Query_ALL function`

```
function db_query_all($arrayParams, $query)
{
global $conn;

$result = $conn->prepare($query);
foreach ($arrayParams as $param) {
    $result->execute([$param]);
}

$rows = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
if (count($rows) < 1) {
    $rows = false;
}
return $rows;
```

}

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in......

db_query_all(Array, 'INSERT INTO `14...')
#2 {main}.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your sample code I think that you must call `execute()` only once. So, istead of:

```
foreach ($arrayParams as $param) {
    $result->execute([$param]);
}
```

Try:

```
 $result->execute($arrayParams);
```

Comment: thanks i think it worked.  But now it is giving me this error  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Comment: I think the problem is I am  Fetching row on insert query! What can be a solution for this is this is a problem!

Comment: Yes, you must not call fetch() after INSERT/UPDATE. Change your call to db_query_all($count_query_params, $count_query); to db_execute($count_query_params, $count_query);

Answer (score 0):

Your query has three placeholders. The array you pass to `db_execute()` has three variables, but you call `$results->execute()` once each for the three variables, binding only one variable each time, hence the message.

Change your `db_execute()` function to call `$results->execute()` just once, but binding all the passed variables in the array at once:

```
// Execute Any Query With Params 
function db_execute($arrayParams, $query)
{
    global $conn;
    $results = $conn->prepare($query);

    $results->execute($arrayParams);

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am think your solution worked but now I am stuck in another Problem